# how to add more attributes to what an api returns

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, auth-token

I am trying to write an API using django rest framework in which, you give a username and a password and in return you get an AuthToken or in other words you login. now I want this API to also return some fields like the email of the user along with the AuthToken. so if the authentication was successful, the get an authToken and the user's email. Can anyone help me on how I could be able to do this by adding or changing a bit of my code?

These are my models:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def createUser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Email Not Found!!!')
        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def createSuperUser(self, email, password):
        user = self.createUser(email, password)
        user.isAdmin = True
        user.isSuperUser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, validators=[RegexValidator(regex="^(?=[a-z0-9._]{5,20}$)(?!.*[_.]{2})[^_.].*[^_.]$")])
    email= models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True,  validators=[EmailValidator()])
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    isSuspended = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    isAdmin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    emailActivation = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    balance = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
```

These are my serializers:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('username','email', 'password', 'name')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'min_length': 8}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return get_user_model().objects.createUser(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        user = super().update(instance, validated_data)

        if password:
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()

        return user


class AuthTokenSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField(trim_whitespace=False)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        username = attrs.get('username')
        password = attrs.get('password')

        user = authenticate(
            request=self.context.get('request'),
            username= username,
            password= password
        )
        if not user:
            msg = 'Authentication Failed.'
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code='authentication')

        attrs['user'] = user
        return attrs
```

And finally, these are my views:

```
class CreateUserView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class CreateTokenView(ObtainAuthToken):
    serializer_class = AuthTokenSerializer
    renderer_classes = api_settings.DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES


class ManageUserView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a new serializer inside serializer.py

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token as DefaultTokenModel
class TokenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = DefaultTokenModel
        fields = ('key', 'user',)
```

add this function in views.py

```
def get_token_response(user):
    serializer_class = TokenSerializer
    token, _ = DefaultTokenModel.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    serializer = serializer_class(instance=token)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

now override post method of CreateTokenView

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    user = serializer.validated_data['user']
    return get_token_response(user)
```

Comment: I also have other fields in the user model, like "balance" which are not needed when creating the user because it is initiated to zero by default.

Comment: sorry. i don't have any single source where i learned. i also faced many problems when i started. recently moshhamedani published django course that might be helpful. you can refer 3rd part of this course. I'm not a student of him and highly encourage you to learn by yourself.

Comment: UPDATE: I added the balance field to the create serializer and made it a read_only field. any better way to do this? ALSO Thanks for the advice, sorry that I edited the first comment.

Comment: yes it is good. serializer can be used to serialize an object or deserialize an object. for more information please refer to official documentation of Django rest framework. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#serializers

Answer (score 0):

For what i understand you just want to return the toekn and the email of the user right? I used this class based view to login users using token authentication.

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken



class UserLoginView(ObtainAuthToken):
    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data,
        context={
            'request':request
        })
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response(
            {
                'token':token.key,
                'email':user.email,
                
            }
        )
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, the previous answer worked. but thanks anyways.